# Datatable saveState not working

Tags: jquery, jsp, datatables

I'm using **jquery datatable version 1.9.4.** What I want is if a user goes to third page and refreshes the page he should be landed on the third page. To accomplish this task I am using the saveState api.

```
$JQ( document ).ready( function() {
   var oTable=$JQ('#t_id').dataTable( {
            "oLanguage" : <jsp:include flush='true' page='...' /> ,
            "bAutoWidth": false,

            <% if(...){ %>
            "aoColumns": [ 
                { "sWidth": "20px",bSortable : false },
                { "sWidth": "45px" },
                { "sWidth": "180px" },
                { "sWidth": "120px", "iDataSort": 10 },
                { "sWidth": "120px", "iDataSort": 11},
                { "sWidth": "100px" },
                { "sWidth": "100px" },
                { "sWidth": "80px" },
                { "sWidth": "60px" },
                { "sWidth": "20px",bSortable : false  },
                { "sWidth": "0px" },// sort by post
                { "sWidth": "0px" } // sort by close
            ],
            <%
            } else {
            %>
            "aoColumns": [ 
                <% if (.... )) { %>
                { "sWidth": "5px" ,bSortable : false },
                <% } %>
                { "sWidth": "45px" },
                { "sWidth": "200px" },
                { "sWidth": "100px" },
                { "sWidth": "100px", "iDataSort": 7 },
                { "sWidth": "100px", "iDataSort": 8},
                { "sWidth": "140px" },
                { "sWidth": "80px",bSortable : false  },
                { "sWidth": "0px" },// sort by post
                { "sWidth": "0px" } // sort by close
              ],

            <% }%>
            "bstateSave": true,
             "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
                    localStorage.setItem('DataTables_' + window.location.pathname, JSON.stringify(oData));
                },
              "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
                    var data = localStorage.getItem('DataTables_' + window.location.pathname);
                    return JSON.parse(data);
                },
            "fnInitComplete": function() {
            // after table is redrawndo something here
                initenhanced();
            },
            "bFilter": true,
            "aaSorting": [],
            "sDom": '<"top"<"clear">>rt<"bottom"lip<"clear">>'
        } );
    }
```

If I monitor my local storage, whenever a page is changed the current state of the datatable is being stored but whenever the page is refreshed the datatable is loaded with the initial state instead of the saved state. Can anyone tell me where possibly I'm going wrong.

**Note : The table in the HTML is populated from jsp tag inside a for loop.**

Comment: which browser?and have checked if cookie is enabled and works?

Comment: cookie is enabled. Checked on chrome and firefox both

Comment: what are you doing on `fnInitComplete`?does it get fired after `fnStateLoad`?may be that is overriding the settings.

Comment: if I comment fnInitComplete the datatable still is loaded with the initial state. Yes it is fired after fnStateLoad

Comment: can you check with version 1.10?see here https://www.datatables.net/blog/2012-01-16 on top section?

Comment: given the circumstances I cannot upgrade my datatable as of now

Comment: I'd suggest upgrading also, but other than that according to the [documentation](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/features) is should be `bStateSave` rther than `bstateSave`...